# C/AL NAV Input textbox

Tags: navision, cal

I am trying get user input the do a calculation and return result as message. The case POS attendant enters amount tendered then the systems returns change to be given to customer.

I have created a dotnet variable #window ***Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.'Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'***

```
Window.InputBox('INPUT','Enter Amount','Amount',100,100);
amount:= amount-"Amount Inc. VAT";
message('%1',amount);
```

I am getting this error when the page runs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GLld.png)

Comment: Set `RunOClient` on variable's properties maybe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `RunOClient` on variable's properties